# Idiom for Change in Game-plan or strategy

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

In light of the coronavirus, I am making a professional presentation about how my company can change its strategy to suit the new situation. Is there a fun idiom or phrase I can use to title this presentation?

Comment: I suppose that's fair. 'Game-changer' has been purloined for wider usage, for instance for the new antibody\test kits soon to be available ([Boris Johnson; Greg Heffer at Sky News](https://news.sky.com/story/coronavirus-game-changer-covid-19-tests-could-be-available-in-days-mps-told-11963509)).

Comment: *To acclimatise its strategy*?

Comment: https://ludwig.guru/s/shift+of+plans; shift in plan/ strategy?

Comment: This idiom comes to mind, although it may not fit your description of "fun": 

2. [refocus](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/refocus) - focus anew; "The group needs to refocus its goals"

Comment: I'm not sure whether I've heard *pivot* used for this. Maybe.